# STM32 HAL with SHT25 from sensirion over I2C,IIC

Tags: sensors, stm32, i2c, hal

Does anyone, who uses STM32 HAL driver, got I2C communication with a Sensirion sensor like SHT25 working and can show me his snippets?

I got communication working using the Code examples from sensirion. (https://www.sensirion.com/fileadmin/user_upload/customers/sensirion/Dokumente/11_Sample_Codes_Software/Humidity_Sensors/Sensirion_Humidity_Sensors_SHT21_Sample_Code_V1.2.pdf) 
I get an Acknowledge when i address the sensor, but when i want to read sensor data, i only get "11111111".

Comment: What have you tried so far? Read the datasheet, there are a list of commands which should be used. Also search for STM32CubeMX and STM32CubeF0/1/2/3/4, plenty of examples.

Answer (score 0):

Working code for Sensirion SHTC1 on STM32 with HAL drivers:

```
#define SHTC1_I2C_ADDR  0xE0
#define TEMP_HUM_CMD_MEASURE_T_FIRST    0x7866

//Launch convert
uint8_t cmd[2];
cmd[0] = (uint8_t)(TEMP_HUM_CMD_MEASURE_T_FIRST >>> 8);
cmd[1] = (uint8_t)TEMP_HUM_CMD_MEASURE_T_FIRST;
HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, SHTC1_I2C_ADDR, cmd, 2, 100);

//Wait
HAL_Delay(15);

//Read values
uint8_t rawValues[6]; //T MSB, T LSB, T CRC, H MSB, H LSB, H CRC
HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, SHTC1_I2C_ADDR, rawValues, 6, 100);
uint16_t rawTemp = (uint16_t)((((uint16_t)rawValues[0])<<8) | (uint16_t)rawValues[1]);
uint16_t rawHum = (uint16_t)((((uint16_t)rawValues[3])<<8) | (uint16_t)rawValues[4]);

float hum = (float)((float)100 * (float)rawHum / (float)65536);
float temp =(float)((float)-45 + (float)175 * (float)rawTemp / (float)65536);
```

Comment: I get an Error at HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit.
What does your MX_I2C1_Init()-Function look like?

Answer (score 0):

Use HAL_I2C_Mem_Write() and HAL_I2C_Mem_Read() HAL APIs for writing and reading data through I2C interface from the sensor. What data to write/read and from which memory location to write/read you have to find from sensor data sheet.

Comment: sensor data is not located in the Memory. the data is acquired after sending a trigger command.

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean by sensor data is not located in the Memory? Can you explain? For any digital thing the data should be stored in some form of memory.

Comment: The datasheet of the SHT25 explains, that a measurement of the sensor is triggered by a command sended by a master. Then the sensor is performing a measurement and when it's ready (after typ. 50 ms), it sends the measured value over I2C to the master. There is no way to read out the sensor's Memory.

Comment: As per I2C specification an I2C slave cann't initiate a data transfer over the I2C bus, only a I2C master can do that. Can you provide link to datasheet?

Comment: https://www.sensirion.com/fileadmin/user_upload/customers/sensirion/Dokumente/2_Humidity_Sensors/Sensirion_Humidity_Sensors_SHT25_Datasheet_V3.pdf